# How to check if function is being run in IDLE or from another function/module

Tags: python, function, program-entry-point

I know that you can do this with modules:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ...
```

and that that runs only if the module itself is being run in IDLE, and not if the module gets imported. However, I want to know if there is a way to check if a function is being run manually in the IDLE interface, or if it is getting called from another function/module. And if there is a way to do this from inside the function, then how would you do this?

Comment: You want to check if it's being run from IDLE's REPL?

Comment: Try working through a tutorial on crawling the run-time stack.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at `inspect.stack()` and try to extract the information you are interested in; for example, I can see that in IDLE at least 2 of the frames tend to come from `idlelib/run.py`.

The following function should do what you say you're looking for, but you can also modify it to suit your needs.

```
import inspect
def is_inside_idle():
    return any(frame for frame in inspect.stack()
               if frame.filename.endswith('idlelib/run.py'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately it returns `False` when run from IDLE, if it was created in a text editor. And it returns True if it was created in IDLE, even if run from another function.